# How to use 2GIS map in iOS app

Tags: ios

Now I don't know how to use 2GIS map in iOS app?

How for example to show pins, my location, routes and so on?

Is there a library? How to use all it's functions?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "How do I use <third party framework or service> questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you look at the bottom of your question you should see options `share edit close delete flag protect`. Click "Delete". (The close button is to vote to close the question as inappropriate. The delete button is only shown for the owner of the question (and possibly for moderators.) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2gis doesn't have ready-made solutions, such as SDK, for mobile platforms. But you can take their data through the API. In this case, it is necessary that your application supports java.

Answer (score 0):

Now 2gis have SDK, for mobile platforms, for iOS:
https://docs.2gis.com/en/ios/webgl/maps/overview

Comment: I Aggree with @Duncan C